# How to add dropdown within HTML Form?

Tags: css, html, forms

I need to add this salutations inside the form attribute.

[image]
Here is the necessary code segment I'm using.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name with Initials</label>
    <select name="name_with_initials" id="">
                  <option selected="selected" value="Operation">Mr.</option>
                  <option value="NPA">Mrs.</option>
                  <option value="BTS-Kurunegala">Miss.</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="name_with_initials" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
```

How to do this?

Comment: I think what you need is JavaScript or Jquery. 
It is a scripting where it defines the behavior of the page or view

Comment: This could be handled by jquery or php embedded in html if u have database to call the peoples name,you can look at [link] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want Mr, Miss or Mrs to be added to a name in a different div? All answers below are basically displaying a dropdown like the one you already had. I assume this code is inside a form, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? Check below snippet.
There is "input-group" class in Twitter Bootstrap, which can give you this result.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<form>
    
    <label>Name with Initials</label>

    
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <select name="sal">
          <option selected="selected" value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
          <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
          <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" oninput="FullName.value = sal.value +' '+ Name.value">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
    <input type="hidden" name="FullName" />
   
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly like this.but problem is when i fill the field of text then press the submit button text is go to the database not including Mr or what else.why is that? do i have to add id feild and text feild name in same?

Comment: I think you have to get values of both fields separately and then combine it before storing it in database.

Comment: u mean do i have to use seperate data attributes as well?

Comment: Please check changes in my answer. Now you have to save this hidden field's value to your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class `form-control` in `select` tag.

```
<select class="form-control" id="">
```

here is the full html

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<form>
    <div class="form-group" style="border:1px solid red;padding:10px;">
    <label>Name with Initials</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="">
                  <option selected="selected" value="Operation">Mr.</option>
                  <option value="NPA">Mrs.</option>
                  <option value="BTS-Kurunegala">Miss.</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This class you added only applies styles. OP already had this code.

Comment: @derloopkat OP has one more `input` tag at the end which uses `form-control` class, so I think he wants a big box which should contains `options` inside it. Also I removed the `input` tag which is of no use there.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a `<form>` and a submit button for the example. Basically, you need to change the value of the option to the text inside, like this:

```
  <option value="Mr." selected>Mr.</option>
  <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
  <option value="Miss.">Miss.</option>
```

and you need to get the value of the `<select>` with some JavaScript/jQuery and put it in a variable, and update it whenever the select is changed. Then, when the form is submitted, you need to get the text in the input and put the variable (and a space) before the text entered.

```js
title = $('#name_with_initials').val();
function titleChange() {
  title = $('#name_with_initials').val();
}
function formSubmit() {
  $('.form-control').val(title + ' ' + $('.form-control').val());
  alert($('.form-control').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <form onsubmit="formSubmit()">
    <label>Name with Initials</label>
    <select name="name_with_initials" id="name_with_initials" onchange="titleChange()">
      <option value="Mr." selected>Mr.</option>
      <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
      <option value="Miss.">Miss.</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="name_with_initials" class="form-control" value="">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```